# R manipulate data from csv file with different number of columns

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm working with the event file dataset from Retrosheet. The raw data is in csv format and I was able to read the data into R. The first column contains the "type" of information, such as ID, info, start, sub but the number of columns varies. Every game in the event file follows the format below: One row for the "ID" followed by 32 rows of "info", 20 rows of "start" (the starting lineup for both teams), and a varying # of rows for "sub" (any batting, pitching or fielding substitutions that occurred during the game).

"","startsub","retroID","playerName","visitorHome","lineupPos","fieldingPos","unused1"

## ** first game in the event file **

"1","id","ANA202007280","","","","",""
"3","info","visteam","SEA","","","",""
"4","info","hometeam","ANA","","","",""
"6","info","date","2020/07/28","","","",""
"7","info","number","0","","","",""
...
"34","start","longs001","""Shed Long Jr.""","0","1","4",""
"35","start","white005","""Evan White""","0","2","3",""
"36","start","lewik001","""Kyle Lewis""","0","3","8",""
"37","start","seagk001","""Kyle Seager""","0","4","5",""
"38","start","lopet001","""Tim Lopes""","0","5","10",""
"39","start","crawj002","""J.P. Crawford""","0","6","6",""
"40","start","moord002","""Dylan Moore""","0","7","7",""
"41","start","smitm007","""Mallex Smith""","0","8","9",""
"42","start","odomj001","""Joseph Odom""","0","9","2",""
"43","start","shefj001","""Justus Sheffield""","0","0","1",""
"44","start","fletd002","""David Fletcher""","1","1","6",""
"45","start","troum001","""Mike Trout""","1","2","8",""
"46","start","renda001","""Anthony Rendon""","1","3","5",""
"47","start","uptoj001","""Justin Upton""","1","4","7",""
"48","start","ohtas001","""Shohei Ohtani""","1","5","10",""
"49","start","pujoa001","""Albert Pujols""","1","6","3",""
"50","start","lastt001","""Tommy La Stella""","1","7","4",""
"51","start","stasm001","""Max Stassi""","1","8","2",""
"52","start","wardt002","""Taylor Ward""","1","9","9",""
"53","start","sandp002","""Patrick Sandoval""","1","0","1",""
"93","sub","cortn001","""Nestor Cortes""","0","0","1",""
"104","sub","ramin002","""Noe Ramirez""","1","0","1",""

## ** next game in the event file **

"191","id","ANA202007290","","","","",""
"193","info","visteam","SEA","","","",""
"194","info","hometeam","ANA","","","",""
"195","info","site","ANA01","","","",""
"196","info","date","2020/07/29","","","",""

I wish to extract the values listed for ID, visteam, hometeam, playersTeamYear, date and number so I can create a new data frame as follows:

"","startsub","retroID","playerName","visitorHome","lineupPos","fieldingPos","gameid","visteam","hometeam","playersTeamYear","date","number"
"53","start","sandp002","""Patrick Sandoval""","1","0","1",ANA202007280,"SEA","ANA",
"ANA_2020","2020/07/28","0"
"93","sub","cortn001","""Nestor Cortes""","0","0","1","",ANA202007280,"SEA","ANA",
"SEA_2020","2020/07/28","0"

Note: "PlayersTeamYear" is determined conditionally based on the value of "visitorHome" for a given row where a zero indicates the player is on the visiting team and a one indicates the player is on the home team.

The end goal is a data frame that will list every player from a particular season which I can sort chronologically, showing every game that they participated in, whether starting or a substitute, what position(s) they played, etc.

I considered using a for loop to iterate through the rows using the "id" row as the separator between each game but I'm not sure if that is the most efficient way to proceed. Additionally I wasn't certain what was the best way to extract that data so I can match it up to the "start" and "sub" rows in a new data frame.

I'm struggling to find a similar example and haven't attempted to write the for-loop or other code yet.

I wanted to produce a loop that collects the data that I need from the specified 'id' and 'info' rows, writes the results to a new dataframe using the 'start' and 'sub' rows for that game, then looks for the next game 'id' and repeats the process.

Comment: Hi. Please format your question according to [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).